# How could I print the result after updating cart by using ajax in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

This is my controller code:

```
function customer_cart_update(){
         $count_cart = count($this->cart->contents());
         for($i=0 ;$i <=$count_cart ;$i++){
             $data_cart = array(
                 'rowid' => $this->input->post('rowid'.$i),
                 'qty' => $this->input->post('qty'.$i),
             );
         }
         //print_r($data);die;
        $data = $this->cart->update($data_cart);
         //Either  print value or send value to database

         echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Ajax code

```
$(".submit").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    var pro_rowid = $("input#Rowid").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "admin_customer/customer_cart_update",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'rowid': pro_rowid},
        success: function(res) {
           //alert('success !');
            $("#Qty").html();
            $("#Result").html();
        }
    });
});
```

and my view code

```
<?php 
                    $a=1;
                    foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $cart_item){?>
                    <li>
                        <ul class="Sub-Cart">
                            <li><a href=""><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>upload/<?php echo $cart_item['options']['Image'];?>"/></a></li>
                            <li><a href=""><?php echo $cart_item['name'];?> <?php echo $cart_item['options']['Size'];?>  <?php echo $cart_item['options']['Color'];?></a> <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin_customer/customer_del_cart/<?php echo $cart_item['rowid'];?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" title="Xoa"></i></a></li>
                            <input type="hidden" name='rowid<?php echo $a;?>' id='Rowid' value='<?php echo $cart_item['rowid'] ;?>' />
                            <li><?php echo $cart_item['price'];?> </li>
                            <li>
                                <input id="Qty" type="text" name="qty<?php echo $a;?>" value="<?php echo $cart_item['qty'];?>" min="1" />
                            </li> 
                            <li  id="Result"><?php echo $cart_item['subtotal'];?></li/>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <?php $a++;}?>
```

I can not update "qty" into the contents of cart ,is there anything wrong?,and how i can show the total of price and the quantity after update ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you're not assigning your response on the element value `Qty`. What is the json response look like?

Comment: Where are you setting the values for `$this->car->contents()`? That's what would contain your 'qty' but I don't see the method declared in your code.

Comment: @bos570 in my cart ,there have already had some values like : id ,qty ,price ... so I use count() for counting the contents.

Comment: #Roljhon So could you show me more about that? I am a new designer ,so that problem is very hard to me ^^

Comment: Someone could give me a clear answer about this  heavy stone ??? plz help me =.=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are lots of things wrong here. your cart items are a list, but the ajax isn't taking that into account, and the qty isn't being sent by ajax to the server.  the ajax should send that data to the server somehow for it to be picked up on.

using the selector input#Rowid is just wrong.  i can't see input with #Rowid in your code, but input is not necessary if #Rowid is defined.

you are iterating through a loop in the view, but each iteration has the same id.  these must be unique in the DOM otherwise it will break.

i suggest you use an array input name, that way the post should work it out and post an array of values.
good luck!